# some products free and some product is not free for shipping

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am having online shopping site.i would like to know if it is possible to enable free shipping with Woo Commerce only if certain items (or items of certain categories / shipping classes) are included in the cart.

Some Product are free ship and some are not.i have set shipping method free ship and flat rate.but its not working. 
Is it possible to do this using some other method ?
I have added shipping class in shipping option first class is Free shipping and second class is Shipping1(which is not free shipping).

Product A has shipping1 and product B has shipping1 but when this both product added in cart only one time shipping is added with Flat rate.

[image]

Comment: you can create a shipping class "free shipping". then, in the settings of the flat rate you can set fees to 0 for this shipping class and another amount for product without classes

Comment: i have created this both ship class one is  free ship and second is shipping 1. but  when i apply flat rate on this if i have two shipping1 ship class product in cart but in calculation it only showing me one product's price is added in. for example. a has class shipping1 and b has same and shipping1's price is 10 so cart is showing only additional 10 not 20.

Comment: edit your question to add all the details about which kind of calculation you want

Comment: @mmm any update?

Comment: to add 10 by product, put "10 * [qty]" in the field in the flat rate configuration